# Where gradle wrapper extracts its disturbutation?

Tags: gradle

I'm using gradlew and for my self, always change distribution url specified in `gradle-wrapper.properties` to local file like below:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
#distributionUrl=file:///d\:/Programs/gradle/dist/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

but for some reason, I need to use its real download url (url will be used in CI/CD that is not located in my PC), but while I have this file, and gradle extracted that, everytime I execute gradlew, gradlew downloads it again, regardless of its bandwidth, it takes some minutes to download.

Because of my low speed network and a lot of failures, I need to manually extract downloaded file in gradle expected destination location.

I need to know where gradle extracts that file (and this location is somehow related to url value, maybe url hash or something related), for example if I set url to `file:/d:/Programs/gradle/dist/gradle-6.7-all.ziP`, gradlew downloads and extracts it in `C:\Users\[User]\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7-all\9o7y0tvu25lma4xv65cg3lmq3`, I guess its last part `9o7y0tvu25lma4xv65cg3lmq3` is hash of a value that is related to distribution url

Does anyone has some idea? or I need to extract and check gradle `gradle-wrapper.jar`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deal with the path of gradle it looks like you should not use the gradle wrapper (gradlew)

if you want to use a specific gradle version you can download and install it by yourself.

just download any distribution from gradle.org.

for exeuction don't call gradlew, just call `gradle` (which is located in the `bin` folder of the gradle download package).